# Error "Magic number checking on storable file failed" when Storable file transferred through SCP

Tags: perl, storable

I had a basic code where it stores a hash in a file.

```
store \%hash 'file';
retrieve ('file');
```

The difference is, the file is transferred to a different machine through SCP and retrieved there. While retrieval, I get this error "Magic number checking on storable file failed". I tried "nstore" too, but that too failed with the same error.

Is SCP the culprit in corrupting file or something? I looked at the file it looks same to me though!
Is there anything i need to take care specifically? Anything else as a suggestion?

Comment: Are you using the same version of `Storable` on both machines?

Comment: Have you checked that the file is being transferred correctly?

Comment: Also, have both machines the same architecture? I am not sure you could read a Storable file created on an 64bits machine in a 32bits one or vice-versa.

Comment: One last thing, the Storable docs have some information about the format of the magic header. You can use a hex-editor to check the file that fails to load.

Answer (score 1):

two things need to be checked:

1. When the retrieve is done, the file should be owned by same user as the user who is running the retrieval code. Even if the current uid has read permissions for that file, different uid creates problem. So copy file under the retrieval user or use chown.
2. check Storable versions in both machines. Though storable is backward compatible.

EDIT::

1. The ownership was not causing the failure. Copying to different file worked for me though.  So suspecting the locking issue in my code (not the ownership). I had a inotify for that directory. That might be the culprit, as pretrieve() in Storable.pm failed.

Comment: So the issue was caused by another user owning the file?

Comment: yes. though there was read permission for the file (like vi works), retrieve() failed.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I don't get an error when a different user owns the file as long as the user running the script has read access. Without read access, I get `can't open /path/to/file: Permission denied`. What version of `Storable` are you using?

Comment: yes i couldn't too in a normal case. So investigated a bit in my actual code and updated the answer. Thanks anyways!